# Access Variable Member

Tags: php, variables

I have an array variable $array like this

```
$array = Array
         (
            [results] => stdClass Object
            (
              [successc] => stdClass Object
              (
                [926] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transaction_id] => xx
                        [transaction_code] => xx
                        [status] => xx
                        [amount] => 5
                    )
              )

              [success] => Array
              (
                [0] => Successful transaction
              )

           )

        )
```

I want to access the transaction_id element. The 926 is a variable value. It could very well be 927 or 928. It comes from another object `$cc`. Would it be correct to access the transaction_id using the following code?

```
$x = $cc->id;
$transaction_id = $array['results']->successc->{$x}->transaction_id;
```

Comment: have you tried this code ? what is error in this code ?

Comment: I have not tried this code. I know it is unfair to ask doubts. But I am operating on a live server and do not want to mess up things

Comment: I think it should work. Just try once the same instance in your local system and then add it in your production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not bad, but the code structure looks more like an array.

To convert to a full array, you can encode to json en decode to array.

```
 $array = json_decode(json_encode($array), true);
```

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So you can access each level of `$array` as array element.